# How to install Pillow For Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner for Python and I'm trying to install pillow so that my program could show the image. I searched the internet but I find it very confusing, I didn't know where to put the command. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

In the command line write:

```
pip install pillow
```

If you are in Windows, you can press Windows key + R and write the command there.

Comment: Yes, without the dot. I have edited my answer to remove it. I realized later.

Comment: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. It's what i get

Comment: You may not have Python added to the path. 
Try to run the command python. If it is executed then prove: python -m pip install pillow

Comment: what do you mean, i dont understand what's run the command python. sorry i'm an idiot.

Comment: In the command line write "python", without the quotes, if it works, run: "python -m pip install pillow" (without quotes, again.) Otherwise you need to add python to your path.